# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable_scope' with TFANN in Colab

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

i start using Colab to create ANN and try out the TFANN package and receive error with the following simple sample code from https://github.com/nicholastoddsmith/pythonml#tfann:

```
pip install TFANN
import numpy as np
from TFANN import ANNR

A = np.random.rand(32, 4)
Y = np.random.rand(32, 1)
a = ANNR([4], [('F', 4), ('AF', 'tanh'), ('F', 1)], maxIter = 16, name = 'mlpr1')
a.fit(A, Y)
S = a.score(A, Y)
YH = a.predict(A)
```

The error i received is: `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable_scope'`
Can someone tell me why i received this error and how can i fix this? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please paste the exact error message that you are receiving? Also, are you using any specific Colab environment (CPU/GPU/TPU)?

Comment: Hi, the exact error message is 'AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable_scope''', i have included the exact error in the post and i don't use any specific Colab enviroment